# How to clone svn ignore structure?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, ignore

I have a package with many subfolders. Each subfolder contains different svn ignores. Now I would like to replace all the folder structure with the new package (which does not contain the ignores). If I copy the paste directly all the ignores are lost. I would like to write an script which copies and then set again all the ignores. How should I do it?

I want to clarify that if there is another method to copy the files without removing the ignores I'm open to suggestions.

Edit: the package I am substituting in my repo is part of another repo but does not have different svn properties

Comment: I did the substitution of the package by manually dragging the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svn:ignore properties are just deleted if you copy the with the file explorer (at least on OpenSuse) performing the copy via command-line with the command:

```
cp -r new-package/* old-package/
```

Does not remove the ignores set on all the subfolders (and recursively all the folders under the first one).

EDIT: I'm not sure whether this is svn normal behavior or just happens under OpenSuse, someone can confirm it?